# How to change color of text filled in by VBA

Tags: vba, colors

I have a code that fills in blank cells based on LEFT 3 symbols from another column like:

```
Set xlCellA = Range("C2")
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Do Until xlCellA.Row > LastRow
If xlCellA.Value = "" Then
xlCellA.Value = Left(xlCellA.Offset(0, 2).Value, 3)
            
End If
Set xlCellA = xlCellA.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
Set xlCellA = Nothing
```

And I'd like it to color that new added text to be vbred. How and where to add that in the code?

Comment: @Eduards a suggestion if you are relatively new to the language: You can very often get a long way towards finding a good solution/understanding the VBA object model by using record macro functionality and then examining the code that is created https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code - this article relates to Word but the concept is identical in Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328775/how-to-change-color-of-text-filled-in-by-vba#comment117263498_66328775) by [braX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422953/brax):

> `xlCellA.Font.Color = vbRed`

My code is thus:

```
Set xlCellA = Range("C2")
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Do Until xlCellA.Row > LastRow
If xlCellA.Value = "" Then
xlCellA.Value = Left(xlCellA.Offset(0, 2).Value, 3)
xlCellA.Font.Color = vbRed
    
End If
Set xlCellA = xlCellA.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
Set xlCellA = Nothing
```